# QBXML - modifying Sales Order line item custom field

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I have a custom field set up in my QB sales order line items called `Ready QTY`, and I want to use QBXML to *update* the value.  Here is a test QBXML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <DataExtModRq>
            <DataExtMod>
                <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                <DataExtName>Ready QTY</DataExtName>
                <TxnDataExtType>SalesOrder</TxnDataExtType>
                <TxnID>52FC6-1504808512</TxnID>
                <TxnLineID>52FC8-1504808512</TxnLineID>
                <DataExtValue>3</DataExtValue>
            </DataExtMod>
        </DataExtModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

My other QBXML requests to the Web Connector work fine (I'm using Keith Palmer's awesome SDK, thanks Keith!).

I think I have the request right, at least according to the reference (https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) under the `DataExtMod` method.  However, QB Web Conenctor returns this error message:

`0x80040400: QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream`

The XML validates, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Has anyone tried to update Sales Order line item custom fields before?  Any help?

#### **The issue above is solved, but I have a RELATED QUESTION that is still unsolved:**

Do I need to put this `DataExtModRq` inside of a `SalesOrderModRq`?  It doesn't seem that way as I look at the OSR.  And it seems like data exts in QB work differently than other entities where I'd pass an `EditSequence` somehow in order for QB to actually update anything...  I'm just passing the TxnID and TxnLineID of the Sales Order line item as well as the data field name I want updated.  QBWC is running my requests without errors and I'm getting a good return XML back in my response handler, but QB itself is not showing the updated value in the field.  Is there a setting in QB or something I don't know about?

The TxnID of the Sales Order I want to modify is 530C4-1504813938, and the TxnLineID is 530C6-1504813938.  I've changed these individually to bogus values to test my request and QBWC does indeed return an error, as expected.

Here's what it looks like on a Sales Order itself:

[IMAGE: Screenshot - Ready QTY field on a Sales Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv9vl.jpg)

Here's some relevant PHP code to what I'm doing.

Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions:

```
$map = array(
QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_SALESORDER => array('_quickbooks_salesorder_import_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_import_response' ),
QUICKBOOKS_MOD_DATAEXT => array( '_quickbooks_salesorder_update_request', '_quickbooks_salesorder_update_response' ),
);
```

The request itself:

```
function _quickbooks_salesorder_update_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="13.0"?>
    <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
              <DataExtModRq>
                  <DataExtMod>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                    <DataExtName>Ready QTY</DataExtName>
                    <TxnDataExtType>SalesOrder</TxnDataExtType>
                    <TxnID>530C4-1504813938</TxnID>
                    <TxnLineID>530C6-1504813938</TxnLineID>
                    <DataExtValue>6</DataExtValue>
                </DataExtMod>
            </DataExtModRq>
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
    </QBXML>';

return $xml;
}
```

Then I enqueue the request:

```
$Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
$Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_MOD_DATAEXT);
```

I run QBWC and I get no errors.  The response XML I receive and print out from my response handler is:

```
[12-Oct-2017 09:47:56 America/Chicago] <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<DataExtModRs requestID="252" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>Ready QTY</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>6</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
</DataExtModRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

This makes it look to me like the value was updated...  However, I look at the particular sales order and line item in QB, and the value is still "4" and not "6".

Is there anything else I can do to see why it is not updating?  Or is there a step that I'm missing in the process?

Comment: This request should work fine, no need to embed it within the Sales Order. Screenshots? Example request/response from real life that didn't work?

Comment: I added some additional detail to the OP.  Thanks for looking Keith!

Comment: Another thing I discovered - I can look at the audit trail report in QB for the particular Sales Order I'm trying to modify, and it indicates that "User (external accountant)" was the one who modified it last.  It also is date stamped with the latest run of QBWC too. But for some reason the custom field itself is just not reflecting the new value, even if I close QB and reopen it. I hope I'm not overlooking something stupid obvious here...

Comment: Keith, any direction you might be able to point me in?  Is there anything else I could try?  I'm still at a total loss as to why the value in the custom field isn't updating in QB itself yet I'm getting a "Status OK" message and successful return DataExtModRs XML from QBWC that shows me the updated value for the field.

Comment: I decided to move away from custom fields and just use the "Other 1" and "Other 2" fields on sales order line items, which I can just update with SalesOrderModRq. I managed to get my custom fields to update, but QB would end up changing the wrong field, even if I specified the correct name in my XML request.  Definitely bugs in QB related to custom fields!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did some research and answered my own question.  I ended up using the QBXML validator included in the SDK that Intuit provides as a free download.  My problem was that I was specifying an old version of QBXML ("2.0") instead of something much more recent.

So the solution was to add:

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
```

to the top of the request.  It was not validating correctly because I originally had

```
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
```

I had cut and pasted it from somewhere else, and initially didn't realize that the version number mattered as much as it does.

I edited the OP so that the QBXML is actually valid now.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into a similar issue!

Comment: A better way to do this might be to use `<?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>` since $version is passed into your function as a parameter.